# How to get comments and the comments' replies out of table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

**I have a comments table.**

[image: Table]

**I want to get the comments and replies out of the table to display them like this. I am just looking for a query so I can do something like this**

[image: What I Want]

**What I Did**
Query I used

```
SELECT c.post_id, c.id AS comment_id, c.user_id, users.username, c.created, c.comment, r.id AS reply_id, r.parent_comment_id, r.created, r.comment AS reply, r.user_id AS reply_user_id, r_user.username as reply_username FROM (comments c) LEFT JOIN comments r ON c.id = r.parent_comment_id LEFT JOIN users ON c.user_id = users.id LEFT JOIN users as r_user ON r.user_id = r_user.id  WHERE r.id OR c.post_id IS NOT NULL ORDER BY parent_comment_id ASC;
```

[image: What I Did]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  c.comment,
  IFNULL(r.comment, '') reply
FROM 
  comments c
  LEFT JOIN comments r
    ON c.id = r.parent_comment_id 
WHERE 
  c.parent_comment_id is null
```